# Get max value from result which contains different string value in group by clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, max, greatest-n-per-group

My table is like this,

```
Field1   |  Field2  |  Field3

2        |    100   |  test1
3        |    100   |  test2
```

I need to get max from this result. so the result should be as follows,

```
3   100   test2
```

my current query is,

```
SELECT MAX(Field1),Field2,Field3 FROM Table1 GRUOP BY Field2,Field3
```

this returns these two rows. but i need only the row which contain the `MAX(Field1)` value.

Comment: Which `group by` clause? Please show us your current query. Also, it would be useful to show more than two rows of sample data, so the logic is clearer to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, you want the row that has the maximum `field1` for each distinct `field2`. Since you want the entire row, aggregation is not the solution; instead, you want to filter.

Here is one way to do it using a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.field1 = (select max(t1.field1) from mytable t1 where t1.field2 = t.field2)
```

Another option uses window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, rank() over(partition by field2 order by field1 desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

Finally, here is a more original approach that uses `with ties`:

```
select top (1) with ties *
from mytable
order by rank() over(partition by field2 order by field1 desc)
```

Comment: it worked for me. what is the best way of those approaches? if consider about cost?